# How to change Django superuser name?

Tags: django

Is there a way to change Django superuser name through cmd windows? If not, what is the other option(s)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say "name" it could be either `first_name`, `last_name` or the `username`
You can do this:

Open cmd, and navigate to the folder with `manage.py` There

```
$ python manage.py shell
> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> user = User.objects.get(username=<superuser's username>) #or email=<email>
> user.first_name = 'first_name'
> user.last_name = 'last_name'
> user.username = 'username' #make sure it is unique
> user.save()
```

Another option is to go to your database table `auth_user` and change it there.