# How can I reset the username in Django if I mistakenly set it wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, superuser

Is it possible to reset the superusername in Django if it was mistakenly set incorrectly? I made an error during the initial setup and need guidance on how to rectify it. What steps can be taken to change or reset the username in Django to ensure accuracy and consistency with the intended information?

I want the solution for reset the superusername n in Django

Comment: you can access by running server and access admin panel and change the username, and there is another way to use terminal.

Comment: If you want to create a new superuser use the command line: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Django superuser name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767390/how-to-change-django-superuser-name)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You can manually update the auth_user table in your database. Open a database client and execute a SQL command to update the username:

```
UPDATE auth_user SET username = '<new_username>' WHERE username = '<old_username>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in admin panel by clicking on Users table, next you click on your
misnamed superuser and in username field type your new name. Remember to save your change at the bottom of the site.